# Memory leak when utilize TTask in dynamic package library

Tags: delphi

Using TTask in a dynamic package, will cause memory leak and access violation in debugger. It seems TTask isn't fit to utilize in dynamic packaged application in some situation.

I define an external procedure in a delphi package:

```
unit LibUnit;

interface

implementation

uses System.Threading, Winapi.Windows;

procedure Test;
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure begin OutputDebugString(PChar('Task Executing')); end);
end;

exports Test;

end.
```

I then consume the procedure in my main application:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Threading,
  Winapi.Windows;

var H: THandle;
    P: procedure;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

  H := LoadPackage('MyPackage.bpl');
  @P := GetProcAddress(H, PChar('Test'));
  P;
  Sleep(1000);
  OutputDebugString(PChar('Start unload package'));
  UnloadPackage(H);

  ReadLn;
end.
```

It prompt memory leak after application close:

```
This application has leaked memory. The small block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered by pointer):

13 - 20 bytes: Unknown x 1
21 - 36 bytes: TThreadPool.TControlFlag x 1
69 - 84 bytes: TTask x 1
```

A sample project may download from [RSP-15316](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15316)

I notice it was due to the new thread created in TTask exit after package was unload:

```
Thread Start: Thread ID: 8308. Process MainProject.exe (6208)
Debug Output: Task Executing Process MainProject.exe (6208)
Debug Output: Start unload package Process MainProject.exe (6208)
Module Unload: MyPackage.bpl. Process MainProject.exe (6208)
Debug Output: Thread Exiting: 8308 Process MainProject.exe (6208) message 'access violation at 0x50067528: read of address 0x02351fb8'. Process MainProject.exe (6208)
Thread Exit: Thread ID: 8308. Process MainProject.exe (6208)
```

If we can find a way to control package unload after the thread to exit, then the memory leak shall not happen anymore.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you put some waiting between the call to P and the UnloadPackage? It is quite possible that the task is not finished when you are unloading the package.

Comment: @UweRaabe, exactly my thought as well. There must be some sort of confirmation that the thread is done, before unloading the package.

Comment: You unloaded the module before its code has finished, no?

Comment: I suggest exporting another function `CanUnload` which checks for this condition. Better check from the main program than blocking inside the package.

Comment: That is not unlike COM's [`DllCanUnloadNow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690368.aspx) function.  When COM wants to unload a DLL, it asks the DLL first.  If the DLL has any COM objects active, it rejects the unload until they have been released first.

Comment: I try to `Sleep(1000)` before unload the package. I also put some `OutputDebugString` statement to make sure the task get executed before unload package.  So far all work as expected but the memory still occur.  I notice it was due to a new thread get instantiated while task was running and the thread exit only when application terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution.  Don't use default TThreadPool instance managed by ThreadPool class itself.  Instead, define own TThreadPool instance and use in TTask:

```
unit LibUnit;

interface

implementation

uses System.Threading, Winapi.Windows;

var ThreadPool: TThreadPool;

procedure Test;
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure begin OutputDebugString(PChar('Task Executing')); end, ThreadPool);
end;

exports Test;

initialization
  ThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
finalization
  ThreadPool.DisposeOf;
end.
```